# Change UIBarButtonItem's button title in inputAccessoryView of UITextView after created?

Tags: swift, uibarbuttonitem, inputaccessoryview

I've created a `inputAccessoryView` for `UITextView` in `viewDidLoad`:

var keyBoardToolBar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 50))
    keyBoardToolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default

```
var firstButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "firstButton", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: Selector("firstButtonAction"))

var flexSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

var done: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self, action: Selector("doneButtonAction"))

var items = NSMutableArray()

items.addObject(firstButton)
items.addObject(flexSpace)
items.addObject(done)

keyBoardToolBar.items = items as [AnyObject]
keyBoardToolBar.sizeToFit()

self.tv.inputAccessoryView = keyBoardToolBar
```

And I want to change the `firstButton`'s button text in other function (after `viewDidLoad`). So how can I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I `var` the `firstButton: UIBarButtonItem` just inside the class before `viewDidLoad` and change it's title use `firstButton.title`. :)